# How to verify ST Link V2 original or fake?

Tags: stm32, st-link

I need your help to identify the product is original or not?

I ordered the ST-Link V2 from one of the local and reputed online website. The product I received has an outer box that looks like original but after seeing the product I think it is not. I just want to know how to verify that the product I received is original or not?

Below are the photos of the product which I received.

[image][image][image][image]

Comment: It'd be a lot easier if you just told us who this reputable seller was.

Comment: [this guy](http://www.00ic.com/others/088d7d9bf74191e0.html) claims one that looks exactly like yours is the domestic China version, but original ST. "ST-LINK/V2 (EN) is the US version, ST-LINK/V2 (CN) is the domestic version.
Both are ST official original products with the same function and slightly different accessories". No idea if it's correct, but it's at least plausible.

Comment: The quality of the moulded plastic (main case and USB) as well as the printing on the main case looks better than what you would expect from the really cheap knock-offs.

Comment: Ask on ST website. They will not blame you if it is fake. IMO it seems similar to the ones I use except the language, it could be a version for Chinese market. The fakes you can buy on the internet do not seem to hide behind an original casing: they are obviously fake.

Comment: Funny thing: I ve just looked at one ST-Link ordered on Amazon 1 month ago and everything look like yours at first sight...but looking closer and comparing it with an older one I already had, the blue  ST link logo on the new one is ugly, the CE logo doesn't look right and the plastic casing is slightly different (the butterfly above the '2' of the upfront "STM32" looks like a star and has nothing to do with a nice butterfly..So mine is definitely a fake one..what about yours ?

Comment: To be honest I am still not in a position to give you the exact answer. I never had an original one in my hand so......But performance-wise it looks good and also i got a good deal in comparison with the tiny fake one.